# How to efficiently style a table inline in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I can style a table in react via:

```
  var tableStyle = {
       "border": "1px solid black"
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My Awesome Table</h1>
        <table style={tableStyle}>
          <th>Awesome Header</th>
```

Coupling my style and html into a reusable component is the react way of doing things.  How can I effectively style my whole table?  I could style each header via:

`<th style={headerStyle}>`
`<th style={headerStyle}>`
`<th style={headerStyle}>`

and

`<tr style={rowStyle}>`
`<tr style={rowStyle}>`

That's not very efficient.  In plain old CSS I can just do

```
 table {
       //boom style all the things
    }
    th {

    }
    tr {
    }
```

Using CSS, particularly in a SPA application can become a maintenance headache.  So I like the idea of sticking my style into this component where nobody else will inherit it.  How can I do it without writing a bunch of repetitive code?

Comment: I take it using regular css classes from a separate css file is not acceptable in your application?

Comment: Polymer scope https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html

Comment: @chris right.  For reasons I mentioned I dont see this as a possibility

Comment: You can't create class names that are guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: I suggest also looking up the information about styling tables on w3schools. They have some very simple to follow instructions on there and great information! http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: Note also there's a course covering styling in react on PS: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-styling-components/table-of-contents

Comment: Have you looked at [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand what you're looking for, but you want a better way of having css and markup in one file with no external dependencies?

If so, this might work:

```
return (
  <style>{`
    table{
     border:1px solid black;
    }
  `}</style>
  <div>
    <h1>My Awesome Table</h1>
    <table>
      <th>Awesome Header</th>
      ...
)
```

Using template literal string formatting seems necessary here to support the `<style>` contents to span across multiple lines.

Alternatively:

```
<style>{"table{border:1px solid black;}"}</style>
```

Comment: I think something like `return ( <div> <style scoped> styles </style> <table> ...` would be better.

Comment: @MrLister, sure. Valid option, but it depends on the component I suppose and we don't know much about it. I think OPs' main issue was how to declare the css rules inside react, rather than how to apply them to each element. I would personally prefer to give the `div` a class and then style each html element that's a child of that div class. -- but that's just preference.

Comment: I want to thank you for writing that <style> example above, I have spent weeks on trying to find a way how to apply a style to a specific component at runtime only as I'm dynamically changing styles/etc. This method seems to work for me!!! thank you!! No need for class names in css etc etc, I love it!!!

Comment: You're welcome @Dariusz! I use a library called emotion (styled-components lib is similar) which gives tons of options to add styles. You could take a look there too.

Answer (score 0):

You should have all of your styles in a separate folder/ and file and maintain separation of concerns. No CSS declarations should be in your JavaScript. If must style your components, you should be using CSS classes instead of inline-styles.

Then you could style all of your tables from one CSS file.

```
/*CSS file*/

table.myAwesomeTable {
  ...code
}

/*Markup */
<table className="myAwesomeTable">

</table>
```

Comment: As long as you are using React I see no issue with inline styles.

Comment: He asked explicitly not to use a separate CSS file

Answer (score 0):

define style in your global theme.js

```
 "table, th, td" :{
      border: "1px solid white" },

      "th, td" : {
        textAlign: "center"
    },
```

All tables in App will now display white border